# What is the difference between the designer.vb page and .vb page?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to framework 3.5. I noticed that when creating a web content form, it creates a aspx.designer.vb page in addition to the aspx.vb page. Can anyone explain the difference to me and the purpose of each?

Comment: The one with designer in the name belongs to the IDE (the **designer**); it's used to store design-time information (autogenerated code, initialization for components you drag and drop at designtime, etc.). A little common sense should have been able to figure this out, new or not. :-(

Comment: @KenWhite: `A little common sense should have been able to figure this out, new or not.` - That's not for certain. Aren't you being a little harsh? Someone that has never programmed before would probably not know. Certainly one could tell that there's a difference when looking at the names and the code, but the OP also asked what the purpose of it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the difference to me and the purpose of each?

`aspx.designer.vb`

Is the designer related autogenerated code by the framework and it contains necessary code for the controls you have placed in your form in designer surface. If you want you can make changes to your controls look and feel using the desinger property window (or) even using this designer file.

`aspx.vb` is the file where the actual server side code block is present. Like your controls event handler methods etc.

consider going through the MSDN documentation for getting a better understanding on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed it too..
I think the .vb file has the code you have written.. and the designer.vb file has options on how to display your code in the screen..
You can open the files with Visual Studio or NotePad++ or just Notepad to see the difference..

Comment: Visual Studio can open them too. :p

Comment: I know ..but I think visual studio opens them as a project,so he can't see the difference..

Comment: It doesn't, or at least shouldn't, when you open a single file via Windows Explorer.